# Listeners and timers in ReactPHP?

Tags: php, events, timer, listeners, reactphp

I'm trying to build a small application which will do a few things.

A main class will spawn, destroy, listen to, and manage workers...

```
<?php

  namespace Queue;

  class Controller extends Process
  {
    public $workers = array();
    function __construct()
    {
      //Run the Process constructor before doing anything else.
      parent::__construct();
    }
    function spawnWorker($businessId)
    {
      $this->workers[$businessId] = new \React\ChildProcess\Process("php index.php worker $businessId");
      $this->workers[$businessId]->start($this->loop);
      $this->workers[$businessId]->stdout->on("data", function($output) use(&$businessId)  {
        $this->channels->out->write("Child $businessId Said: " . $output);
      });
    }
    function outputToWorker($businessId, $string)
    {
      $this->workers[$businessId]->stdin->write($string);
    }
    function run()
    {
      $this->loop->run();
    }
  }
```

A bunch of workers managed by the controller (eventually they will have a long running process which manages a queue defined in the database)...

```
<?php

  namespace Queue;

  class Worker extends Process
  {
    function __construct($businessId)
    {
      //Run the Process constructor before doing anything else.
      parent::__construct();
      // Assign a business to this worker.
      $this->businessId = $businessId;
      // Create a queue object for this worker.
      $this->queue = new \stdClass;
    }
    function run()
    {
      $this->channels->in->on("data", function($input) {
        $this->sendOutput($input);
      });
      $this->loop->run();
    }
  }
```

However, I ran across a situation where code did not do what I expected...

```
// Based on command line argument, decide which kind of process to spawn.
  if (!isset($argv[1]) || $argv[1] === "controller")
  {
    $controller = new Controller;
    $controller->spawnWorker(1);
    $controller->outputToWorker(1, "Before Run");
    $controller->run();
    $controller->outputToWorker(1, "After Run");
  } else if (strtolower($argv[1]) === "worker" && isset($argv[2]))
  {
    $worker = new Worker($argv[1]);
    $worker->run();
  }
```

This last bit of code is the file which I actually run to start the application. It routes which kind of process should be spawned based on command line arguments. (This way I don't have to have a file for a bunch of different kinds of processes.)

The worker is spawned correctly, and the first message (`Child 1 Said: Before Run`) is sent to the worker, the worker sends it to `stdout` and the `controller` hears that event and sends it to it's own `stdout`.

However, it seems the listener is a one-time listener, and the event loop is not reprocessing it over an over. Meaning, anytime after the initial `run()` on `controller` it will not respond to `stdout` events from the worker.

Do I have to create my own explicit listeners with timers?

Comment: Where does `$this->loop` come from? I don't see it set anywhere.

Comment: I should have added that. Both the worker and the Controller extend process which creates properties and instances for each class's loop and communication channels.

Comment: Please add it to your code, I guess you have two loops somewhere.